# What sort of action is it to designate a creature as prey?

Tags: ranger, pathfinder-2e

The [Hunt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=9) feat gives a Ranger bonuses against a creature, they seem to be able to re-designate a target endlessly it seems within the same day:

> You can have only one creature designated as your prey at a time. If
>   you use Hunt Prey against a creature when you already have a creature
>   designated, the prior creature loses the designation and the new prey
>   gains the designation. Your designation lasts until your next daily
>   preparations.

This Feat is tagged *Concentrate* and *Ranger*.

A couple of questions to clarify things I'm not sure on:

1. Can a Ranger endlessly re-designate targets to hunt during a day?
2. How many actions (if any) is it to designate a new target?

Answer (score 12):

[Hunt Prey](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=10) takes a single action, as can be seen from the symbol next to the name. The rules text does not specify any limitations on how often the ability can be used, so you can designate targets as often as you like, provided you're willing to spend a single action each time.

Comment: Aha! Still getting the hang of 2e notes and indicators - thanks!

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Swift Prey is gained by all Rangers at 19th level and reduces it to a Free Action if you do it before spending other Actions on your turn.